# On Jetpack Compose, why is Text not recentered on recomposition?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

On my Android app, I am trying to make a composable that displays data in form of a table.
I want each column to be as wide as it needs (with a max width), so for this, I need to display everything and change the width on each row according to the widest row.

So far I have this, which works pretty well:

[image: Table]

The problem comes when a row is wider than the ones before, the previous rows change to the right width, but the text alignment doesn't work (I added a background color to the Texts so we can see they do get wider):

[image: Table with misalignments]

As you can see, they are aligned based on the previous width and I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun TableCell(
    text: String,
    style: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
    width: Dp = 0.dp,
    onWidthSet: (Dp) -> Unit = {},
    maxColumnWidth: Dp = 100.dp
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    fun Int.asDp() = density.run {
        this@asDp.toDp()
    }

    Text(
        text = text,
        style = style,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .widthIn(width, maxColumnWidth)
            .onSizeChanged { onWidthSet(it.width.asDp()) }
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun DataTable(
    headers: List<String>,
    rows: List<List<String>> = emptyList(),
    maxColumnWidth: Dp = 90.dp
) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
        ),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 6.dp
        )
    ) {
        val columnWidths = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Dp>() }
        val onWidthSet: (Int, Dp) -> Unit = { index, width ->
            if (!columnWidths.containsKey(index)) {
                columnWidths[index] = width
            }
            else if (columnWidths[index]!! < width) {
                columnWidths[index] = width
            }
        }
        LazyColumn {
            stickyHeader {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                ) {
                    headers.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                        TableCell(
                            text = title,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall.copy(
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                            ),
                            width = columnWidths[index] ?: 0.dp,
                            onWidthSet = { width ->
                                onWidthSet(index, width)
                            },
                            maxColumnWidth = maxColumnWidth
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            items(rows.size) { index ->
                val row = rows[index]
                Row {
                    for (i in headers.indices) {
                        TableCell(
                            text = if (i < row.size) row[i] else "",
                            width = columnWidths[i] ?: 0.dp,
                            onWidthSet = { width ->
                                onWidthSet(i, width)
                            },
                            maxColumnWidth = maxColumnWidth
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(
    apiLevel = 33,
    showBackground = true,
    device = Devices.TABLET
)
@Composable
private fun DataTablePreview() {
        DataTable(
            headers = listOf("Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", "Header 4"),
            rows = listOf(
                listOf("Row 1", "Row 1", "Row 1", ""),
                listOf("Row 2", "-- Wider Row 2 --", "", ""),
                listOf("Row 3", "Row 3", "Row 3", "")
            ),
            maxColumnWidth = 200.dp
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this problem on emulator run:

[image]

Your problem propably lays in use of your lambda function `onWidthSet()` within `onSizeChanged`. I think preview cannot evaluate this properly what ends in incorrect display in preview. [image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked and it does work using the 'Run Preview' option, but doesn't on the preview or on the app. For the app it might be because it's a debug version though, haven't had the chance to check on a release APK